# joomla, change alias in com_menus

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Can someone pinpoint me to where alias in com_menus is changed because I need to add to url few values and Joomla is striping `&` and `%` etc

i have something like this :

```
mysite.com/going?3DPA%26tt%3DF%26sd%3D*3%26ed%3D*20%26drf%3D6%26drt%3D15%26a%3D2%26at%3D33554432%26st%3DPA%26sp%3D2
```

and Joomla is creating this:

```
mysite.com/going-3dpa-26tt-3df-26sd-3d-3-26ed-3d-20-26drf-3d6-26drt-3d15-26a-3d2-26at-3d33554432-26st-3dpa-26sp-3d2
```

How do I prevent it from changing anything?

Comment: What ae you entering as the alias? WHat kind of menu link? Is it an external link? Joomla is going to use url safe aliases.  If you hae a ? in the link it looks like you are not using an alias but instead are making a query. T

Comment: I"m pretty sure that Joomla does this to make sure that you don't conflict with any query items that it may have to add. Disabling this could have some nasty consequences (and wouldn't be easy).

Instead, you likely want to update the xml file for the menu item to allow you to add parameters that way. What does the menu item link to? (Custom component, standard component?)

Comment: Custom component, and where is that `xml` file ?

Answer (score 0):

The menu alias is determined by Joomla AND the component's router.php.
My best guess to get you out of this issue is just base64encode your param so Joomla sees it as a single param. Then add it to the view default.xml with a string value, this way Joomla should be able to build the SEF route; just check your router.php and debug it if it's not behaving as expected.
In order to have SEF routing correctly, you will need to create a menu item pointing to the view; if you don't need it, just hide it in a hidden menu.